# How to pull invoice number from PNR

Tags: sabre

I am trying to retrieve the invoice number of a PNR from the Sabre API.
Can anyone advise the correct API to use?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can use the [TravelItineraryHistoryLLSRQ](https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/soap_apis/management/itinerary/get_itinerary_history/resources) API or the [getReservationRQ](https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/soap_apis/management/itinerary/retrieve_itinerary/resources) to gather invoice numbers on all accounting lines. If using the getReservationRQ API, take a look at the fields in the documentation related to InvoiceData.

If you are more familiar with reading native Sabre responses you could also use the [SabreCommandLLSRQ](https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/soap_apis/management/utility/send_sabre_command/resources) API with the entry "*HAC" to bring back a list of all of the historical accounting lines and accompanying invoice numbers, but that gets a little difficult to parse out.